# how to upload image in swift 2 to php server

Tags: php, mysql, json, swift2

I am trying to upload photos to my database in my server from my iPhone app. the language I am using is swift 2. please help me. I am attaching my code to upload the other details to the JSON link and I want to add image also to my link. please help me

```
import UIKit


class MealViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, 

UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

// MARK: Properties

@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ratingControl: RatingControl!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Handle the text field’s user input through delegate callbacks.
    nameTextField.delegate = self

    let attributes = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor(),
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 2)!
    ]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes

}



// MARK: UITextFieldDelegate

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Hide the keyboard.
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

}

// MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    // Dismiss the picker if the user canceled.
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    // The info dictionary contains multiple representations of the image, and this uses the original.
    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
    photoImageView.image = selectedImage

    print("my image ", photoImageView)

    // Dismiss the picker.
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: Actions
@IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Hide the keyboard.
    //nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let isLoggedIn:Int = prefs.integerForKey("ISLOGGEDIN") as Int
    if (isLoggedIn != 1) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_login", sender: self)
    } else {
        self.usernameLabel.text = prefs.valueForKey("USERNAME") as? String
    }
}


@IBAction func ratingSubmitButton(sender: UIButton) {

    print(ratingControl.rating)
    print(self.usernameLabel.text!)


    let name:NSString = self.usernameLabel.text!
    let value = ratingControl.rating


    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photoImageView.image!)



    do {
        let post:NSString = "name=\(name)&value=\(value)"

        NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://kiran.com/insert.php")!

        let postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

        let postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )




        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = postData
        request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")




        var reponseError: NSError?
        var response: NSURLResponse?

        var urlData: NSData?
        do {
            urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            reponseError = error
            urlData = nil
        }

        if ( urlData != nil ) {
            let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

            NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

            if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
            {
                let responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

                //var error: NSError?

                let jsonData:NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary


                let success:NSInteger = jsonData.valueForKey("success") as! NSInteger

                //[jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];

                NSLog("Success: %ld", success);

                if(success == 1)
                {
                    NSLog("Login SUCCESS");

                    let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                    prefs.setObject(name, forKey: "USERNAME")
                    prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                    prefs.synchronize()

                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_rating", sender: self)
                } else {
                    var error_msg:NSString

                    if jsonData["error_message"] as? NSString != nil {
                        error_msg = jsonData["error_message"] as! NSString
                    } else {
                        error_msg = "Unknown Error"
                    }
                    let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                    alertView.title = "Rating Failed"
                    alertView.message = error_msg as String
                    alertView.delegate = self
                    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                    alertView.show()

                }

            } else {
                }
        } else {
            }
    } catch {
        let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alertView.title = "Rating Success!"
        alertView.message = "Thank You"
        alertView.delegate = self
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alertView.show()
    }

}













@IBAction func logOutButton(sender: UIButton) {

    let appDomain = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(appDomain!)

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_login", sender: self)
}
```

`